# Storing object type in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to store object type in to variable instead of creating actual object. Based on the type, I would like to create object when ever I needed.

I've tried the below method to get the type

```
function getType(obj){
        var text = Function.prototype.toString.call(obj.constructor);
        return text.match(/function (.*)\(/)[1];
}
```

But issue with above method, it calls constructor to the get the type name.

I don't want to initialize the object until i actually needed.

Any thoughts.

Thanks
Naren

Comment: So you want to get the type of an object, without really having an object ?

Comment: And why not just `typeof obj` ?

Comment: I want get class name based on class. Example type(MyClass) should return "MyClass".

Comment: typeof(Foo).Name -- Need something similar in JavaScript

Comment: Why do you think your function would call the `constructor` or create an actual object?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
function getType(fn) {
    return fn.name || fn.toString().match(/function\s+([^(\s]*)/)[1];
}
```

which can call both with

```
function Class() {}
getType(Class) // "Class"
```

or

```
var instance = new Class;
getType(instance.constructor) // "Class"
```

Notice that you should not use this in production. There are js implemenations that neither support [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) nor [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) on functions. Set a custom `.type` property or so on your constructors where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
function getClassName(obj){
  return obj.constructor.name;
}
```

Comment: I want to pass class name and in return should get class name in string. For Example : function getClassName(typeof(className)){
  // return classname in string
}

Comment: typeof(Foo).Name -- Need something similar in JavaScript

Comment: I don't think you are clear enough, your first comment I quite can't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just calling the `toString()` function?

```
function getType(obj) {
    var text = obj.toString();
    return text.match(/function (.*)\(/)[1];
}
```

In the following sample the *result* variable will contain "Demo" and the constructor won't be called:

```
class Demo {
    abc:any;
    constructor(a: number) {
        this.abc = a;
    }
}
var result = getType(Demo);
```